# Вертикальный разделитель в весь контейнер

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как правильно сделать разделитель между блоками #right и #left высотой в весь контейнер?

В сниппете использован border-right, но он размером только с высоту блока. Как сделать разделитель, который будет от границы с нав.панелью и до границы с футером?

Желательно без JS

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -115px;
  padding: 0 0 115px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.footer {
  height: 115px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #acacac;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#right {
  border-right: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrap">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MySite.com</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4" id="right">
        <p>
          some text here
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8" id="left">
        <p>
          another text here
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div clas="col-xs-12">
        <p>
          Some footer info
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kqhw8jfc/

Answer (score 1):

Для любого из блоков задать псевдо-элемент :before или :after и для него выставить соответствующую высоту.
Например так: https://jsfiddle.net/0ctwa9co/

```
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #dadada
}

.right {
  float: right
}

.left:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  height: 115%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -6px;
  top: -15px
}
```

Для контейнера можно также задать overflow: hidden, а для "разделителя" высоту, явно большую, чем сам контейнер.